# clang can't find headers but gcc can

Tags: gcc, clang

Using ubuntu 22.04, g++ can compile my test program with no issues. clang++ on the other hand will fail with...

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  cout << "hello world" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I also have a cmake/c++ project that will compile just fine with gcc, but when I reconfigure it to use clang I get the following output from cmake.

```
~/C/vkf % cmc && cmake ./ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Ninja" && ninja
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/david/C/vkf/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_ef4ce && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef4ce.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_ef4ce
    FAILED: cmTC_ef4ce 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef4ce.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_ef4ce   && :
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/david/C/vkf/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/david/C/vkf/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

in my CMakeError.log

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
```

Something must have been changed in my system configuration, because both of these worked fine before. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Was having the exact same problem! Solved by completely uninstalling & reinstalling the `libc++-dev` apt package.

Comment: tied that, still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing **cpp-12** package or install **libstdc++-12-dev**.

Comment: I have had the same problem under 18.04 and 22.04
with clang 10 and clang 14. Installing libc++-dev
did not help. Removing cpp-12 did not help.
But installing libstdc++-12-dev DID help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it a very similar issue I had by installing libc++abi-dev:

```
sudo apt install libc++abi-dev
```